# how do I debug an error being returned by loadMedia on the mediacontrolchannel

Tags: ios, chromecast

I have the following a customer receiver and the following scenerio:

1. I connect to it, load the application and play media
2. The media finishes playing and the receiver unloads the application (but stays
       connected)
3. I load the application (since it is already connected)
4. I try to play media (via loadMedia) and it returns 0 (kGCKInvalidRequestID)

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you doing to unload the application, yet staying connected?

Comment: we do a stop on the castreceivermanager 10 seconds after we stop playing the media.  The ios logger shows that the heartbeat is still going (ping in/pong out messages after the application has been unloaded)

Comment: The fact that you see the heartbeat after calling stop() on CastReceiverManager is rather strange; when you call that, does your receiver go back to the chromecast home screen or not? That stop() method should break the connection as well, hence there shouldn't be any heartbeat. You should also get a callback to the effect that application has stopped, do you get that?

Comment: It does go to the home screen.  I do get the callback that the app has unloaded (which I now use to close the connection from the sender side).

Comment: We are looking into it.